# I used gdb to track 'catch' and 'syscall' failed, it reports to not find 'brk'?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, try-catch, system-calls

I did a small experiment of gdb's catch option, under ubuntu16.04, as below:

```
$ cat e.cpp
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<exception> 
int main() 
{ 
  try{ 
    throw 1; 
  }catch(std::exception e) 
  { 
  } 
  exit(0); 
}
```

$ gcc e.cpp -g -lstdc++ 
$ gdb a.out

```
... 
Reading symbols from a.out...done. 
(gdb) catch throw 
Catchpoint 1 (throw) 
(gdb) catch syscall 
Catchpoint 2 (any syscall) 
(gdb) r 
Starting program: /home/a/cpp/a.out  

Catchpoint 2 (call to syscall brk), 0x00007ffff7df12e9 in __brk (addr=addr@entry=0x0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/brk.c:31 
31    ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/brk.c: No such file or directory.
```

What does this error indicate? If I use 'r' comand again, the program terminates:

```
(gdb) r 
The program being debugged has been started already. 
Start it from the beginning? (y or n)
```

This is so weird. How and why I get this brk error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set syscall catchpoint in gdb without any arguments you set it on all syscalls, see in [Setting Catchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html):

> If no argument is specified, calls to and returns from all system
>   calls will be caught.

This is what gdb is telling you after you have done it:

```
(gdb) catch syscall 
Catchpoint 2 (any syscall)
```

Then you ran the program and immediately caught `brk` syscall. This is not surprising because `brk` syscall is used for dynamic memory allocation implementation (actually for `malloc` implementation) and your program of course do some memory allocations.

When syscall was caught, gdb tried to print line number 31 in brk.c for you but failed because most likely libc sources are not installed in your OS. You should ignore this error because you are not debugging libc code and just experimenting with catching syscalls.

What you could probably want, is to look at `bt` to see where are you allocating memory in your code.